How to pass a value from a chrome popup to chrome main window
I'm working on a ReactJS project for a Chrome extension and facing a challenge in passing data from a Chrome popup to a parent component in the main Chrome window. I'm using the react-new-window library to handle multiple windows.
Context: I have a data grid (using MUI's DataGrid) in the Chrome popup, and I want to allow users to click on a row, which then stores the clicked row's data in a context (ScheduleContext). The goal is to make this data available in a parent component that is opened in a new window.
Here's how I set up my context and components:
ScheduleContext.js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ScheduleContext = createContext();

export const useScheduleContext = () => useContext(ScheduleContext);

export const ScheduleProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [selectedRowData, setSelectedRowData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedRowData) {
      console.log('Selected Row Data:', selectedRowData);
    }
  }, [selectedRowData]);

  return (
    <ScheduleContext.Provider value={{ selectedRowData, setSelectedRowData }}>
      {children}
    </ScheduleContext.Provider>
  );
};


MainOrderList.js (Chrome Popup)
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import OrderAPISvc from '../../../../api-layer/order-svc';
import { useScheduleContext } from 'src/context/ScheduleContext';

function MainOrderList() {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const { setSelectedRowData } = useScheduleContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOrders = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await OrderAPISvc.getAllAvailableOrders();
        setOrders(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to fetch orders:', error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchOrders();
  }, []);

  const handleRowClick = (params) => {
    const rowData = params.row;
    setSelectedRowData(rowData);
  };

  return (
    <DataGrid
      rows={orders}
      columns={columns}
      loading={loading}
      onRowClick={handleRowClick}
    />
  );
}

export default MainOrderList;

Schedules.js (Parent Component)
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useScheduleContext } from 'src/context/ScheduleContext';

export default function Schedules() {
  const { selectedRowData } = useScheduleContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedRowData) {
      console.log('Selected Row Data Updated:', selectedRowData);
      // Handle the data (e.g., update UI, etc.)
    }
  }, [selectedRowData]);

  return <div>Schedule Component</div>;
}

Issue:
Is it possible to access the context data from the parent component (in the new window) after a row is clicked in the data grid of the Chrome popup?
If so, how do I ensure the context updates are reflected correctly in the parent component?
Any insights or examples of how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
